# Logback filter doesn't filter out the desired class

Tags: logging, logback, logback-classic

I'm trying to filter out the class "net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise" from my Logback logging.  I've tried two methods, neither of which works.  My logback.xml looks like this:

```
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="com.websudos.loggers.ClassNameFilter">
        <className>net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise</className>
        <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="debugfile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>debugFile.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>debugFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<filter class="com.websudos.loggers.ClassNameFilter">
    <className>net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise</className>
    <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
</filter>

<!-- Setup the Root category -->
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    <appender-ref ref="debugfile"/>
</root>
```

This results in the following log file:

```
2020-11-06 09:12:54,063 1566 [main] DEBUG n.s.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Sending SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: reason=[BY_APPLICATION], msg=[] 
2020-11-06 09:12:54,063 1566 [main] DEBUG net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise - Setting <<transport close>> to `SOME` 
2020-11-06 09:12:54,063 1566 [main] DEBUG o.m.D.DownloadWebSiteBackups - Successfully finished DownloadWebSiteBackups 
2020-11-06 09:12:54,063 1566 [reader] DEBUG net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader - Stopping
```

As you can see from the second logging statement, neither filter worked.  Why not?

EDIT:
The following code works, but I prefer to do it in the logback.xml file:

```
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logger = ( ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger ) LoggerFactory.getLogger( "net.schmizz" );
logger.setLevel( Level.INFO );
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the errors.  It should look like:

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
    <className>net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise</className>
    <level>DEBUG</level>
    <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    <onMismatch>ACCEPT</onMismatch>
</filter>
```

The filter class name was wrong and the level was missing.